# facebook iframe app keeps loading homepage in internet explorer no matter what links are clicked

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook, iframe, page-refresh

I ran into a strange problem these days. One of my apps which is using iframe for displaying inside canvas page is not working in Internet Explorer. Whenever I click a link (part of my app) in IE a `session` variable is added to the query string and instead of loading the requested page it's loading the homepage of my app.

I have to say that using firefox or chrome this problem doesn't exists. Do you have any thoughts what might causing this only in IE? And what should I do in order to fix it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is because IE does not allow third-party cookies.
Since facebook is using iframe, your applications cookies are not accepted by IE.
That causes the problem with session, but that's not the case with ff or chrome.
So to be able to use session you need to set P3P header to force IE to accept third-party cookies.

Comment: You're right, this was the problem. I added a p3p header and it looks like it should to.